# trying to use /dev/uinput to turn on built-in webcam

Tags: linux, webcam, inject, keystroke

Basically, I would like to turn on my notebook's built-in webcam from a shell or shell script, without having to phisically press `Fn+ESC` every time I want to turn it on.

I've been trying to activate the integrated webcam in my lemote [yeeloong 8089B notebook](http://www.gnewsense.org/Projects/Lemote), by using /dev/uinput, under debian squeeze, with kernel 2.6.32-loongson-2f #1 PREEMPT from [bjlx](http://www.bjlx.org.cn/loongson/squeeze/kernel/). I have already achieved activating the WLAN by using uinput, but I can't get the camera to turn on with uinput. Normally, I would press `Fn+ESC` to turn the camera on, but with uinpuit it just doesn't seem to work. The camera works, and can be tested by:

```
mplayer tv:// -really-quiet -tv driver=v4l2:device=/dev/video0 </dev/null
```

I am using the following program (based on HOWTOs by Gregory Thiemonge and Mehul Patel) to try to activate my webcam using uinput (sorry if the code's a little ugly, I kinda wrote it in a rush):

cam_wlan.c:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <linux/input.h>
#include <linux/uinput.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define end(arg) do { \
    perror(arg); \
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE); \
} while (0)

static int fd = -1;
struct uinput_user_dev uidev;
struct input_event ev;

int setup_uinput_dev();
void cam();
void wifi();
int destroy_close();

int main(void) {
    setup_uinput_dev();
    cam();
    wifi();
    destroy_close();
    return 0;
}

int setup_uinput_dev() {
    fd = open("/dev/uinput", O_WRONLY | O_NDELAY);
    if(fd < 0)
        end("Unable to open /dev/uinput\n");
    memset(&uidev,0,sizeof(uidev));
    strncpy(uidev.name, "uinput-sample", UINPUT_MAX_NAME_SIZE);
    uidev.id.version = 1;
    uidev.id.bustype = BUS_USB;
    if(ioctl(fd, UI_SET_EVBIT, EV_KEY) < 0)
        end("Unable to setup UINPUT device.\n");
    if(ioctl(fd, UI_SET_KEYBIT, KEY_CAMERA) < 0)
        end("Unable to setup UINPUT device.\n");
    if(ioctl(fd, UI_SET_KEYBIT, KEY_WLAN) < 0)
        end("Unable to setup UINPUT device.\n");
    if(write(fd, &uidev, sizeof(uidev)) < 0)
        end("Unable to write to UINPUT device.\n");
    if(ioctl(fd, UI_DEV_CREATE) < 0)
        end("Unable to create UINPUT device.\n");
    return 0;
}

void cam() {
    memset(&ev, 0, sizeof(ev));
    ev.type = EV_KEY;
    ev.code = KEY_CAMERA;
    ev.value = 1;
    if(write(fd, &ev, sizeof(struct input_event)) < 0)
        end("Unable to write to UINPUT device.\n");
    ev.type = EV_SYN;
    ev.code = SYN_REPORT;
    ev.value = 0;
    if(write(fd, &ev, sizeof(struct input_event)) < 0)
        end("Unable to write to UINPUT device.\n");
    memset(&ev, 0, sizeof(ev));
    ev.type = EV_KEY;
    ev.code = KEY_CAMERA;
    ev.value = 0;
    if(write(fd, &ev, sizeof(struct input_event)) < 0)
        end("Unable to write to UINPUT device.\n");
    ev.type = EV_SYN;
    ev.code = SYN_REPORT;
    ev.value = 0;
    if(write(fd, &ev, sizeof(struct input_event)) < 0)
        end("Unable to write to UINPUT device.\n");
}

void wifi() {
    memset(&ev, 0, sizeof(ev));
    ev.type = EV_KEY;
    ev.code = KEY_WLAN;
    ev.value = 1;
    if(write(fd, &ev, sizeof(struct input_event)) < 0)
        end("Unable to write to UINPUT device.\n");
    ev.type = EV_SYN;
    ev.code = SYN_REPORT;
    ev.value = 0;
    if(write(fd, &ev, sizeof(struct input_event)) < 0)
        end("Unable to write to UINPUT device.\n");
    memset(&ev, 0, sizeof(ev));
    ev.type = EV_KEY;
    ev.code = KEY_WLAN;
    ev.value = 0;
    if(write(fd, &ev, sizeof(struct input_event)) < 0)
        end("Unable to write to UINPUT device.\n");
    ev.type = EV_SYN;
    ev.code = SYN_REPORT;
    ev.value = 0;
    if(write(fd, &ev, sizeof(struct input_event)) < 0)
        end("Unable to write to UINPUT device.\n");
}

int destroy_close() {
    if(ioctl(fd, UI_DEV_DESTROY) < 0)
        end("Unable to destroy UINPUT device.\n");
    close(fd);
    return 0;
}
```

I compile with

```
gcc -o cam_wlan cam_wlan.c
```

Before running `cam_wlan`, one must, as root:

```
modprobe uinput
lsmod | grep uinput
ls /dev/uinput
```

to confirm that the uinput device has been activated.

The problem I'm having is that, when I run `cam_wlan`, the WLAN LED toggles, but the webcam doesn't. Normally, when I press `Fn+ESC` to toggle the built-in webcam, `dmesg` would show:

```
[45254.379000] usb 1-1: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 15
[45254.536000] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=064e, idProduct=a114
[45254.536000] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=1, SerialNumber=3
[45254.536000] usb 1-1: Product: USB 2.0 Camera
[45254.539000] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: SuYin
[45254.539000] usb 1-1: SerialNumber: CN0317-S30C-MC03-VS-B20081113
[45254.546000] usb 1-1: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice
[45254.550000] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device USB 2.0 Camera (064e:a114)
[45254.567000] input: USB 2.0 Camera as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:09.1/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/input/input896
```

`lsusb` would show:

```
Bus 001 Device 015: ID 064e:a114 Suyin Corp.
```

and running `evtest /dev/input/event2` as root would show:

```
Input driver version is 1.0.0
Input device ID: bus 0x19 vendor 0x0 product 0x0 version 0x0
Input device name: "HotKeys"
Supported events:
  Event type 0 (Sync)
  Event type 1 (Key)
    Event code 113 (Mute)
    Event code 114 (VolumeDown)
    Event code 115 (VolumeUp)
    Event code 142 (Sleep)
    Event code 212 (Camera)
    Event code 224 (Brightness down)
    Event code 225 (Brightness up)
    Event code 227 (?)
    Event code 238 (?)
  Event type 5 (?)
    Event code 0 (?)
Testing ... (interrupt to exit)
Event: time 1364796475.137014, type 1 (Key), code 212 (Camera), value 1
Event: time 1364796475.138119, -------------- Report Sync ------------
Event: time 1364796475.138145, type 1 (Key), code 212 (Camera), value 0
Event: time 1364796475.138159, -------------- Report Sync ------------
```

None of that happens, though, when I run `cam_wlan`. I should mention that no event reporting happens either for the WLAN toggle when running `cam_wlan`, although the WLAN LED does toggle (and the WLAN does get activated and deactivated by running `cam_wlan`), whereas the webcam does not toggle.

I've also tried substituting, in the original cam_wlan.c, the lines

```
...
    if(ioctl(fd, UI_SET_KEYBIT, KEY_WLAN) < 0)
...
    ev.code = KEY_WLAN;
...
```

with

```
...
    if(ioctl(fd, UI_SET_KEYBIT, KEY_FN_ESC) < 0)
...
    ev.code = KEY_FN_ESC;
...
```

but that didn't work either.

So, I'm open to suggestions. What else could I try in order to activate my integrated webcam from a shell? (i.e., not having to phisically press `Fn+ESC` on my keyboard to do so)

Comment: The uinput HOWTOs may be found here: http://thiemonge.org/getting-started-with-uinput http://www.einfochips.com/download/dash_jan_tip.pdf

Comment: Unfortunately pdf file is missing :-(